# WPF toolkit DataGrid - space after the last row on Scrolling

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid, wpftoolkit

I am creating a wrapper for Datagrid. Main point is to have possibility to set summary/footer rows at the end.

Generally I've solved this task, but I have a space between the last row and the datagrid's footer (only if I have more rows than can be displayed without scrolling). Of course I can set

```
ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll="False"
```

but it will cause performance problems. Is it possible to configure datagrid to scroll smoothly to the last row?

[image: Dagagrid with a space after the last row]

and here no problem if we are not at the last row

[image]

**UPD1**
According to [why setting ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll to false disable virtualization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3724593/why-setting-scrollviewer-cancontentscroll-to-false-disable-virtualization) suppose it cannot be solved without losing performance.

Comment: Do you have an in-place editing enabled? Namely the `CanUserAddRows`? (it's on by default) :)

Comment: @Trustme-I'maDoctor CanUserAddRows is set to false. But it's not the solution.