# WPF DataGrid sort on Virtualised attribute

Tags: c#, wpf, sorting, datagrid

Let me get straight down to it. I have a DataGrid with a few set columns, like this:

```
<ctrl:DataGridWithFooter 
      FooterRowsCount="1" 
      x:Name="MyGrid" 
      CanUserDeleteRows="False" 
      CanUserSortColumns="True"
      AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
      ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Model, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" 
      IsEnabled="{Binding Path=Idle}">
                <DataGrid.Columns>
                    <DataGridTextColumn Header="Level" 
                                        Binding="{Binding Path=Name, Mode=OneWay}" />
<!--Snip-->
</ctrl:DataGridWithFooter>
```

And a model as you'd expect. As the application runs, though, I have the situation where I'll add new columns that reflect an element in a list in the model, so I get a binding expression like

```
<DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Path=Attributes[0]}" />
```

or something similar. Displays and sorts fine on its own, but I ran into an issue where I needed to force a row for my totals to the bottom, which I ended up needing to use a bit of code I found online to get it working ok ([available here, works as advertised](http://pro.ingens.ru/2012/07/cwpf-datagrid-footer-row.html)). However, I found his sorting classes in this new customised DataGrid class crash out with my list element bindings. My question is, how would I modify this constructor

```
public PropertyAccessor(Type targetType, string property) {
    IsList_ = false;
    mTargetType = targetType;
mProperty = property;

    PropertyInfo propertyInfo =
        targetType.GetProperty(mProperty);

    mCanRead = propertyInfo.CanRead;
    mCanWrite = propertyInfo.CanWrite;
    mPropertyType = propertyInfo.PropertyType;
}
```

In order to get all the information I need to be able to reflect out and sort on the list elements?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am glad to see that u used my sample (it's my blog). One of the ways to accomplish this - is to create a public getter for specific attribute. Not very convenient may be. Cuz **PropertyAccessor** requires property. Or may be to parse "Attributes[0]" get firstly value of the property and than get element with index [0]

Also I've decided to create another solution for this task. The main idea is to create a wrapper for datagrid. Generally it looks like:

```
<StackPanel>
    <DataGrid/>
    <Footer/>
</StackPanel>
```

Footer is a **Grid** with textboxes (it can contain multiple rows). **Columns** in this Grid are synchronized with Columns of **DataGrid**. Also it allows to create footer with merged cells.
In this solution you don't need to make any moves for sorting. It will be accomplished by **DataGrid**.

[Here is how it looks like](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11870274/wpf-toolkit-datagrid-space-after-the-last-row-on-scrolling). I will share the code on blog a little bit later. You can get me in touch on my blog.

Comment: Yeah, that's essentially what I've done as a work around, found a "Synchronised Grid" class which lets you pin two or more grids together. Your solution is great, and is a component that I've thrown into a library for use later on, but just doesn't seem to fit here unfortunately. Thanks for your help!

Comment: @HeadBangingSloth Could you send your solution into my blog, i'd like to see it. or even here.

Comment: Sorry, can't read the Russian on your page, but the thing I used is [here](http://thibaud60.blogspot.com.au/2010/02/footer-on-wpf-datagrid-by-use-several.html)