# WPF: Preventing TreeView scrolling to top when an item inserted

Tags: c#, wpf, treeview

I'm trying to keep the scroll position of `TreeView` control even when an item is inserted.
`ItemsSource` in the `TreeView` is set by code and it shows items using `DataTemplate`.

When I insert an item to the data source at 0, the `TreeView` will automatically scroll up by the height of the new item.
Actually this feature is useful when scroll-position is at the top, but even if not it scrolls up.
(I'm using `TreeView` for Virtualizing items with `CanContentScroll` set to `false`.)

How can I prevent this default behavior?

WPF 4.0 / C# - Visual Studio 2010 on Windows 7

Comment: Not related but since you mentioned, one info - `Setting CanContentScroll to false disables UI virtualization`.

Comment: I set VirtualizingPanel as the ItemsPanel and VirtualizingPanel.IsVirtualizing to true. It makes TreeView UI virtualized one. (Not affects on ListBox / ListView) Sorry for my less information, thanks.

Comment: That's fine but setting `CanContentScroll` will disable virtualization. Read more [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3724593/why-setting-scrollviewer-cancontentscroll-to-false-disable-virtualization).

Comment: As a result, setting of `CanContentScroll` was ignored because of customizing template.
I didn't know that behavior in case of using `VirtualizingStackPanel` as `ItemsPanelTemplate`.
(This is maybe because `VirtualizingStackPanel` always uses pixel-based scrolling and `CanContentScroll` doesn't make sense.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I solved this problem by handling `ScrollChanged` event of `ScrollViewer`.
Then write in codes like this:

```
var border = VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(sender as TreeView, 0) as Border;
var scrollViewer = VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(border, 0) as ScrollViewer;

// Set the last vertival offset at global variable.
LastVerticalOffset = e.VerticalOffset;
scrollViewer.ScrollToVerticalOffset(e.VerticalOffset + e.ExtentHeightChange);
```

Thank you all.

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem a while ago, and couldn't find a "solution" for the actual issue, but I found a workaround to it.

Find the event where an item is added, and when that is triggered, set the selected item index to that of the amount of items -1 (select the last item).

Comment: SelectedIndex is not defined in TreeView control and SelectedItem is readonly. How can I solve it? Thanks.

Comment: I haven't used the TreeView control a lot, but perhaps this may be of use? There must be a programatic way of selecting a node, and I suspect you might need to set an "IsSelected" property...
http://www.daniweb.com/software-development/csharp/threads/352865/selecting-a-child-node-in-treeview-by-index

Comment: I tried to select the last item by `IsSelected` property of `TreeView.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromIndex` but it still scrolls up to the top.
I made sure that the event is fired and selection is successfully done. (TreeView.SelectedItem has been changed.)
Any ideas? Thanks a lot.

Comment: I'm all out of ideas beyond that, sorry... I think I actually had it with a ListBox, so I could simply set the SelectedIndex. All I can offer further is advice to find something about dynamically selecting TreeView items... Good luck!