# WPF smooth touch scrolling with virtualisation in .Net 4.5.2

Tags: wpf, xaml

Is it possible with 4.5.2 to achieve a list (either from ItemsControl or using ListView/ListBox) with smooth, pixel-based scrolling, virtualised and with touch scroll to allow finger/flick scrolling on a touch screen?

I can achieve the smooth scrolling with virtualisation, but if I were to lose any of these, the preference would be virtualisation, so to have smooth touch scrolling for a non-virtualised list would be great.

Code so far:

IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True"
         ScrollViewer.PanningMode="VerticalOnly"
         VirtualizingStackPanel.IsVirtualizing="True"
         VirtualizingStackPanel.ScrollUnit="Pixel">

```
<ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
        <!-- the item in the list -->
    </DataTemplate>
</ListBox.ItemTemplate>
```

Comment: Look into the Surface 2.0 run-time. There's built in WPF controls that have flick/touch scrolling capabilities.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to setting `ScrollViewer.PanningMode=".."` which will enable touch input, try setting `ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll="False"` on your ScrollViewer or at the internal ScrollViewer of your ListBox/ListView.

This should do the trick, but unfortunately this will also stop the virtualisation from working. See the Remarks at the [MS Documentation for CanContentScrollProperty.](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.scrollviewer.cancontentscroll(v=vs.110).aspx)

For more Information check out the answers on

[this qustion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3724593/why-setting-scrollviewer-cancontentscroll-to-false-disable-virtualization)

[or this one.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1033841/is-it-possible-to-implement-smooth-scroll-in-a-wpf-listview)